# Write Tweety (python module)search results To CSV

Tags: python, twitter, csv

Here is the simple code I'm using:

```
import tweepy

result = tweepy.api.search(q="McDonalds ",rpp=1000,page=2, geocode= "34.085422,-117.900879,100mi" )

for tweet in result:
    print tweet.text
    print tweet.geo
```

It returns the results I want.  In my IDE I get results like this:

```
@stevo_k14 I'm going back after mcdonalds haha

None

“@FunnyEvil: If bars can't serve drunk people, Mcdonalds shouldn't be able to serve fat people.”

{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [33.9581, -118.1779]}

Mcdonalds for breakfast? Yup i think so :)

None

@JessicaCarrillo You make me want to go out to McDonalds right now!!!!! Lol good morning.

{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [33.9443, -118.0038]}
```

Some return no location and some return location.  What I'd really like to do is write the results straight to a csv file with Keyword, Tweet, Lat, Lon as my headers.  Keyword would be "McDonalds" in this case.  It would also be nice to have some ifelse statement to not write results unless they have location.

I am new to programming so your help is much appreciated!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the csv module and iterate over your existing tweet.

```
import tweepy
import csv

keyword = 'McDonalds '
result = tweepy.api.search(q=keyword,rpp=1000,page=2, geocode= "34.085422,-117.900879,100mi" )

with open('some.csv', 'w') as acsv:
    w = csv.writer(acsv)
    w.writerow(('Keyword', 'Tweet', 'Lat', 'Lon'))
    for tweet in result:
        lat, lon = tweet.geo if tweet.geo else ('', '')
        w.writerow((keyword, tweet.text, lat, lon))
```

Comment: Do I need to create a blank csv and then put the path name in 'some.csv'?

Comment: I replaced 'some.csv' with 'C:\temp\results.csv'.  the 'results.csv is blank.  The error i get is:                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Niemann\Desktop\simplesearch.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open('C:\temp\results.csv', 'r') as acsv:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\temp\results.csv'

Comment: Sorry, should've been `w`, not `r`. You're writing the CSV, not reading it. By the way, [read about reading and writing files](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and [the csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Comment: Yes I tried that before my last post and should have included that.  I still get the same error with a 'w' instead of 'r'

Comment: I changed code to this and made it to the last line `keyword = 'McDonalds '
result = tweepy.api.search(q=keyword,rpp=1000,page=2, geocode= "34.085422,-117.900879,100mi" )
csvfile = r'C:\temp\results.csv'
with open(csvfile, 'w') as acsv:
    w = csv.writer(acsv)
    w.writerow(('Keyword', 'Tweet', 'Lat', 'Lon'))
    for tweet in result:
        lat, lon = tweet.geo if tweet.geo else ('', '')
        w.writerow((keyword, tweet.text, lat, lon))`

Comment: So I made it to the last line and I get this error:   w.writerow((keyword, tweet.text, lat, lon))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @niemoy If you read that csv documentation you'll see why that happens.

Comment: Yes I just don't understand it all yet.  I'm just still so new to this.  I think the problem is that the second line is in utf-8?  And I need to convert to string?  When I get a few more minutes I will try to add some more code from that module and see if it works.  Thanks kojiro

Comment: @niemoy no, the problem is that the characters are *not* utf-8. Convert them to utf-8 for better results.

Comment: So this finally worked:     `import tweepy
import csv

keyword = 'McDonalds '
result = tweepy.api.search(q=keyword,rpp=1000,page=2, geocode= "34.085422,-117.900879,100mi" )

with open(r'C:\Temp\results.csv', 'w') as acsv:
    w = csv.writer(acsv)
    w.writerow(('Keyword', 'Tweet', 'Lat', 'Lon'))

    for tweet in result:
        lat, lon = tweet.geo if tweet.geo else ('', '')

        try:
            a = tweet.geo['coordinates']
            print a[0] , a[1]
            print tweet.text
            w.writerow((keyword, tweet.text, a[0] , a[1]))
        except:
            pass`