# Output Tweepy TwitterStreamer to .csv from Python 2.7

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, twitter, export-to-csv

I have a file written in Python that goes out to the Twitterstream and grabs messages based on keywords in a list. The list is very long and the output is not all that I want. I would like to clean up the file and also output the results to a text file.

Here is my current code, which writes all messages to a single line:

```
import sys
....

if __name__ == '__main__':
     with open("keywords.txt", "r") as f:
         keywords = f.readlines()


    l = StdOutListener()    
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)    
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)    

    stream = Stream(auth, l)        
    stream.filter(track=keywords])
```

The above does not pull anything in, meaning nothing is output to a text file when I type the following at the command prompt `python hashtagworking.py > output.txt`
There are about 300 items in the `stream.filter` so I would like to use a txt file in place of the actual text. Also the results show up on one line for each message which is how it is written, I would like to rewrite it to output to a csv file for each object in the message.

I think this is what I am looking for but would like to make sure: [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855042/write-tweety-python-modulesearch-results-to-csv/10855193#10855193)

I would also like to get things from other nested objects like entities: {...} specifically I'd like to get hashtag from the entities object but more specifically any object. I have tried things like `data.text.hashtag` `data.entities.hashtag` `data.entities.media.hashtag` all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your keyword issue, assuming you've put them all in a txt file (one token per line)

```
with open("tokens.txt", "r") as f:
    tokens = f.readlines()

....
stream.filter(track=tokens)
```

For your other questions (output in .csv) could you write down an example of what you'd want in the file ?

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):        
        """ A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
        This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.

        """        
    def on_status(self, data):            
        try:                
            print '%s , %s , %s , %s' % (data.text,\ <-- change to data.csv?               
            data.author.screen_name,data.created_at,data.source)
            with open("data.csv", 'a+') as f:
                f.write("{text},{name},{created},{source}\n"
                        .format(text=str(data.text), 
                                name=str(data.author.screen_name), 
                                created=str(data.created_at), 
                                source=str(data.source)))               
            return True            
        except Exception, e:                
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e                
            pass        

    def on_error(self, status):            
        return True
```

Note that is NOT an acceptable long-term solution as you're opening and closing the file each time a tweet is filtered from the stream (aka flooding I/O), what you could do would be to implement a buffer (each time the buffer is filled up, dump it to file).

Please note that I'm writing in the csv file manually, if you want more depths in the csv manipulation please have a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Thank you @ketouem as for the csv file, I am looking to dump in anything that gets delimited in the code, if I have 5 elements one day and then add a 6th the next day I would want the 6th element to get added. I will go about the documentation that you listed, I also have to figure out how to break out elements from the `entities` portion, I may have to define as a function maybe or just learn how to break out the json.

Comment: I updated the code to what I am working with for an issue now

Comment: Note that you can easily manipulate the raw json data with the eponym (& builtin) module http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html